# Hibernate 5.2.x "Transaction already active" weird behavior

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, jta

While migrating from Hibernate 4.x to latest Hibernate 5 version, I'm encountering an issue with regards to transaction management.

In my code, there is a transaction manager that begins a JTA transaction, followed by a call to a `Session.beginTransaction`. Below is an example that reproduces the issue (the scenario is not using Spring or any other container managed transaction management):

```
transactionManager.begin();
saveOrUpdate(entity1);
saveOrUpdate(entity2);
...
transactionManager.commit();

private void saveOrUpdate(SomeEntity entity) {
    try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
        session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.AUTO);
        session.beginTransaction();   // throws IllegalStateException "Transaction already active"
        try {
            session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This is causing an **`IllegalStateException` to be thrown with the message `"Transaction already active"`**. This behavior seems to have been introduced in Hibernate 5.2.0 ([this is the commit](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/87e3f0fd28d7229b0a35032292ff32f542c22010#diff-b5b02ca2eeaba38219072211329429ae)). **Previously, Hibernate just ignored the beginning the physical transaction itself because it knows an enclosing transaction is present**: it just creates a wrapper `JtaTransaction` with `isInitiator` set to false.

This exception is thrown in `org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl`, specifically the `begin()` method:

```
@Override
public void begin() {
    if ( !session.isOpen() ) {
        throw new IllegalStateException( "Cannot begin Transaction on closed Session/EntityManager" );
    }

    if ( transactionDriverControl == null ) {
        transactionDriverControl = transactionCoordinator.getTransactionDriverControl();
    }

    // per-JPA
    if ( isActive() ) {   // *** This is the problematic part *** //
        throw new IllegalStateException( "Transaction already active" );
    }

    LOG.debug( "begin" );

    this.transactionDriverControl.begin();
}
```

This also contradicts with the [user manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#transactions-physical-jtaplatform), where it says the below:

```
// Note: depending on the JtaPlatform used and some optional settings,
// the underlying transactions here will be controlled through either
// the JTA TransactionManager or UserTransaction

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
try {
    // Assuming a JTA transaction is not already active,
    // this call the TM/UT begin method.  If a JTA
    // transaction is already active, we remember that
    // the Transaction associated with the Session did
    // not "initiate" the JTA transaction and will later
    // nop-op the commit and rollback calls...
    session.getTransaction().begin();
```

Is this a bug in Hibernate? And what does the "per-JPA" comment mean exactly in the code that throws the exception? Is there a way to restore the old behavior?

Comment: Can you please post all the code of your method where you use the transaction? And what runtime enviroment do you have?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thanks for the comment. I elaborated on the code. The environment is a standalone app using Hibernate with a custom TM.

Comment: Ok but why do you call session.beginTransaction()  after transactionManager.begin()? You already have a transaction from the TransactionManager so Hibernate is right when it complaints.

Comment: Actually the code is part of a unit test, and the code that opens a Session and closes it is in a method that is called repeatedly (updated the code again). The goal is to verify that all of the invocations reuse the same XA connection that is maintained by the `TransactionManager`. I understand this may not make perfect sense, but what I can't understand is how the user manual explains it whereas it actually does not work when a JTA transaction is already active.

Comment: It seems the change in Hibernate 5.2.0 was done to comply with JPA's [`EntityTransaction`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/EntityTransaction.html). Seems JPA requires this error? But the weird thing is that, again... it contradicts with the example in the user manual.

Comment: I recommend to file an issue in Hibernate JIRA https://hibernate.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: FYI https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13076 inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually a "regression" that I reported in https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13076 which is now fixed ([here's the PR link](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/2630)).

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour is as expected ok: You began a transaction at the transactionmanager.
I presume it is working according to JTA. Therefore the connection you received for openSession is  expected to take part in the transactionmanagers already started transaction.

Starting an additional transaction must lead to this Exception.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I too think that this is expected. However, it used to work in Hibernate 4 (actually prior to Hibernate 5.2.0), and the user manual's section quoted in the question sort of implies that my code should work (i.e. that the `session.beginTransaction()` knows that it is inside an already open transaction). I also couldn't find a reference (e.g. in JTA) that confirms that the exception is indeed expected. FYI I inserted https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13076 in Hibernate's project to track this.